# Agregating data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace, group-by, aggregation

I am currently working on creating a CCAM thesaurus.
Under pandas I have in my dataframe two code and label fields such as:

> AHQP002 | Electromyography by surface electrode, with video recording,
> without specialized technical platform for AQMM
>
> AHQP002 | Electromyography by surface electrode, with video recording,
> with specialized technical platform for AQMM

How to merge these lines keeping only:

> AHQP002 | Surface electrode electromyography, with video recording

ignoring what is different, i.e. *"without specialized technical platform for AQMM"* and *"with specialized technical platform for AQMM"*

I have several lines in this configuration because of the pmsi extension added to certain codes. Any idea how to handle this?

| code | label |
| --- | --- |
| AHQP002 | Electromyography by surface ..., without specialized technical platform for AQMM |
| AHQP002 | Electromyography by surface ..., with specialized technical platform for AQMM |
| JKFC002 | Subtotal hysterectomy, by laparoscopy, without robot assistance |
| JKFC002 | Subtotal hysterectomy, by laparoscopy, with robot assistance |

```
df = df.groupby('CODE').agg({ 'LABEL': lambda x: list(set(x))[0], 'EXTENSION':'first'}).reset_index()
```

I used this script but for the wording it keeps only the first

> Electromyography by surface electrode, with video recording, without
> specialized technical platform for AQMM

without deleting the part *", without specialized technical platform for AQMM"*

Comment: is the piece you are looking to remove always after the last comma?

Comment: in the majority of cases yes, there are some specific cases that I can adjust by hand !

Comment: try `df['label'] = df['label'].str.rsplit(',',n = 1).str[0]`

Answer (score 0):

This bunch of code extracts commons strings grouped by `code` as values for `label` column.

```py
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

data = {'code':['AHQP002', 'AHQP002','JKFC002','JKFC002'],
        'label': ['Electromyography by surface ..., without specialized technical platform for AQMM', 
                  'Electromyography by surface ..., with specialized technical platform for AQMM', 
                  'Subtotal hysterectomy, by laparoscopy, without robot assistance', 
                  'Subtotal hysterectomy, by laparoscopy, with robot assistance']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def labelize_on_common_s(g):
    s1, s2 = g['label'].iloc[:-1].tolist(), g['label'].iloc[1:].tolist()
    common_s = []
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        matches = SequenceMatcher(None, s1[i], s2[i]).get_matching_blocks()
        match = matches[0]
        common_s.append(s1[i][match.a:match.a + match.size])
    g['label'] = min(common_s, key=len) # Shortest common string
    return g
    
df = df.groupby('code').apply(lambda g:labelize_on_common_s(g))

print(df)
```

**Results**

```
      code                                        label
0  AHQP002        Electromyography by surface ..., with
1  AHQP002        Electromyography by surface ..., with
2  JKFC002  Subtotal hysterectomy, by laparoscopy, with
3  JKFC002  Subtotal hysterectomy, by laparoscopy, with
```

After that you could do some cosmetic operations by replacing linking expression `, with` by `''` :

```py
df['label'] = df['label'].str.replace(', with', '')
```

Final result is :

```py
      code                                  label
0  AHQP002        Electromyography by surface ...
1  AHQP002        Electromyography by surface ...
2  JKFC002  Subtotal hysterectomy, by laparoscopy
3  JKFC002  Subtotal hysterectomy, by laparoscopy
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion which puts me on the right track.
The aspect that remains to be seen is for example in the example, I would like to keep 'Electromyography by surface ...' and remove everything that follows which should give me as the final result:
       label code
0 AHQP002 Electromyography by surface ...
1 JKFC002 Subtotal hysterectomy, by laparoscopy